# How to run multiple Flash CS6 instances at the same time?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I want to run multiple instances of Flash IDE CS6 at the same time, but when I run Flash.exe existing window gets focus instead of running a new one. Is there some kind of a command line switch to run multiple instances at once?

What I am trying to achieve, is to run multiple JSFL scripts at once on my build machine to enable concurrent building.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with a normal configuration.  Flash probably writes to the registry, and having multiple instances running at the same time could cause corruption as they try to write to the same values and perhaps in different orders; in other words, it's not thread-safe or transactional.

It is possible to run multiple instances on the same machine by using a sandbox application like [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/), and you'd need at least the Pro version to run multiple sandboxes at once.

With each instance in its own sandbox, each instance would behave as though it's the only instance running on the machine.

The problems with the sandbox approach are: First, everything is sandboxed, including all writing to the disk, so all the changes are lost when the sandbox closes or the machine is restarted, unless you persist the changes to disk... and you'd probably have to do that manually by interacting with the sandboxing software. Second, automating the instantiation of each sandbox and persisting those changes may be difficult or impossible, depending on the sandboxing software.  Third and finally, the overhead of the setup/persistance/teardown of sandboxes may hinder performance more than you'd gain from the parallel processing.